# Adding new form fields based on a number input

Tags: javascript, html, webforms

I'm trying to get this to work where when a user types in a number and it creates the corresponding number of input fields. I've tried with onclick and onchange and nothing seems to happen. Any idea what I'm missing?

```js
var siblings = document.getElementById('siblings');
  var value = siblings.value;

  siblings.onchange = function(){
    let i = 0;
    do{
    var newField = document.createElement('input');
    newField.setAttribute('type','text');
    newField.setAttribute('name','siblingInfo[]');
    newField.setAttribute('class','siblingInfo');
    newField.setAttribute('siz',50);
    siblings.appendChild(newField);
    i++
    }
    while (i < value);
  }
```

```html
<i>Do you have any siblings?&nbsp;</i>
   <input type="number" id="siblings" name="siblings" min="0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points in your code needs to change:

1. `let value = siblings.value;` should be inside the `onchange` function
2. `siblings.appendChild(newField);` can change to `siblings.appendChild(newField);` since `siblings` is `input` type and can not append child

```js
var siblings = document.getElementById('siblings');

  siblings.onchange = function(){
    let value = siblings.value;
    let i = 0;
    do{
    var newField = document.createElement('input');
    newField.setAttribute('type','text');
    newField.setAttribute('name','siblingInfo[]');
    newField.setAttribute('class','siblingInfo');
    newField.setAttribute('siz',50);
    
    // to make each element in one line we can add a br element before the newField
    siblings.parentNode.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    
    siblings.parentNode.appendChild(newField);
    i++
    }
    while (i < value);
  }
```

```html
<div> 
  <i>Do you have any siblings?&nbsp;</i>
   <input type="number" id="siblings" name="siblings" min="0">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I realized I was reading your reply wrong. It works!

Comment: @Robert have you tested my code? `parentNode` is the `div` element(it added by myself)

Comment: Yes, I realized I was reading it wrong. That worked!